# Making a PDF output in raster format instead of vector using itextsharp

Tags: itext, pdf-generation

I have written C# code to save product specifications to a PDF document using iTextSharp, mainly with PdfPTable and Chunks/Paragraphs in the PdfPCells. However, I have been told that the output is unacceptable due to the fact that you can highlight and copy the text from the document and document storage and retrieval server software that they are currently using does not support "Vector" based PDFs.  I'm not exactly certain what the difference is between a raster pdf and and vector pdf.  Basically, every page of the PDF Document should be an image so that the text can not be highlighted.  Is there any way to do this without using the DirectContent?  Below is an image, illustrating a portion of the PDF that was created, and how the text can be selected and copied, which is the incorrect functionality.

I would like to avoid directly writing to the canvas, unless there is a way to do this and still have itextsharp handle my formatting and proper paging.

The windows application [PDF2R](http://www.wizards.de/~frank/pdf2r.html) works well, but doesn't seem to offer any programmatic solutions.  I have found libraries that stated that they do this sort of conversion, but are several thousand dollars.  I'd like to work within my budget and use the itextsharp or something much cheaper than this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try to generate an image using the System.Drawing class and then insert that into the PDF document.

Comment: i do not believe that is going to work because, like the DirectContent, that will totally negate the pdf generation libraries ability to format, word wrap, and paginate the document properly.

Answer (score 1):

Call this code on your PdfWriter object:

```
writer.SetEncryption(PdfWriter.STRENGTH40BITS, null, null, PdfWriter.AllowPrinting);
```

This won't prevent users from selecting text, but it will prevent them from copying and pasting it.  Give it a try.